# How to add custom Web Console Tab in CQ5

Tags: aem

I am new in CQ5 and I would like seek help on how will I be able to add a new custom console in my CQ instance. If you guys can give me a walkthrough or a reference which I can use. I'm trying to search for answers but I failed to get one.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the login and welcome screens by copying the relevant code in /libs/cq/core/content, /libs/cq/core/components, /libs/wcm, etc. to the corresponding /apps node(s), just the same way you would customize an ordinary content-handling component.  Some references in the CQ5 docs:

- http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_cq.html#Removing%20CQ%20Sign%20Out%20Links
- http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/customize_siteadmin.html